# Room entity with two tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Is it possible to create Room Entities with two tables? I know it's not best practice to store duplicate data, but I need a backup table to restore data to its original state.

```
@Entity(tableName = "models", "backupModels")
public class Entity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "model")
    private String model;

    public Entity() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Merge the tables into a single table  (i.e. add all columns from both into one table), but as you mentioned this violates the basic rules of database

Comment: I'm loading data from Firestore using Entity.class and caching the data locally, so I don't want to have duplicate fields in Firestore, only when I'm caching the data.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create Room Entities with two tables?

**No the @Entity defines a single table only.**

You could just copy the Entity renaming the class and using another set of Dao's.

**However**, if it's only for back purposes then perhaps consider the following working example (designed to just run once).

This is based upon the [CREATE TABLE ? AS SELECT statements](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#create_table_as_select_statements) and for the restore [INSERT INTO table SELECT ...;](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

You only need the single Entity without any changes (other than removal of the 2nd table name). **Entity** :-

```
@androidx.room.Entity(tableName = "models"/* can't do, "backupModels"*/)
public class Entity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "model")
    private String model;

    public Entity() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

A very basic @Dao **AllDao** (to allow demonstration):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract long insert(Entity entity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM models")
    abstract List<Entity> getAllModels();
}
```

The backup/restore code is coded within the @Database **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {Entity.class},version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static final String SUFFIX_BACKUP = "_backup", SUFFIX_OLD = "_old";

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"my.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void backupTable(String table) {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + table + SUFFIX_BACKUP + "`;");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `" + table + SUFFIX_BACKUP + "` AS SELECT * FROM `" + table + "`");
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    public static void restoreTable(String table) {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + table + SUFFIX_OLD + "`");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `" + table + SUFFIX_OLD + "` AS SELECT * FROM `" + table +"`;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM `" + table + "`;");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `" + table + "` SELECT * FROM `" +table + SUFFIX_BACKUP + "`;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + table + SUFFIX_OLD + "`;");
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

- Note the `restore` and `backup` methods can cater for any table. However, adherence to constraints may have to be considered (e.g. if using Foreign Key constraints).
- The **restore** method creates a further backup (optional) as a just-in-case backup (models_old). `DROP`ping the models_old table is optional.

Putting it all together and demonstrating is **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        Entity e = new Entity();
        e.setId(1);
        e.setModel("Model1");
        dao.insert(e);
        TheDatabase.backupTable("models");
        e.setId(2);
        e.setModel("Model2");
        dao.insert(e);
        for(Entity entity: dao.getAllModels()) {
            Log.d("PRERESTORE","ID = " + entity.getId() + " Model = " + entity.getModel());
        }
        TheDatabase.restoreTable("models");
        for(Entity entity: dao.getAllModels()) {
            Log.d("POSTRESTORE","ID = " + entity.getId() + " Model = " + entity.getModel());
        }
    }
}
```

- So this:-

  1. adds 1 row to the models table.
  2. does the backup.
  3. adds a 2nd row to the models table.
  4. writes the contents of the models table to the log (2 rows).
  5. restores the models table (to when 1 row existed).
  6. writes the contents of the restore models table to the log (1 row).

**Result**

When run the log includes :-

```
2021-07-27 07:41:11.991 D/PRERESTORE: ID = 1 Model = Model1
2021-07-27 07:41:11.992 D/PRERESTORE: ID = 2 Model = Model2


2021-07-27 07:41:11.996 D/POSTRESTORE: ID = 1 Model = Model1
```

- **NOTE** Please consider the restrictions when using [`CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ....`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#create_table_as_select_statements)